# Blender already rigged and animated characters

Tags: animation, rigging

I have 4 different characters (Person, Dog, Cat and Rabbit). I have rigged and animated all the 4 characters separately, each in different blender file. Now, i want to make a scene with all the four characters so my question is how do i get all the 4 characters (Animated and Rigged) together in one blender file to make a scene with all of them ?
Also, i want to project this onto something so i need them to be together.

Comment: Have you tried File -> Append ?
Make sure you have saved the animations you make for each file by clicking the shield icon in the animations layout

Comment: You can either try to append or you can literally open the blend file with a character, select the mesh and rig, then ctrl+c, then in the separate scene you want them in ctrl+v

Comment: @hatinacat2000 so i have tried File -> Append but the issues with that method is the PATH that i have for all of these files are different so when i play them in a loop, two out of four meshes rotates in odd angles deforming the entire mesh.

Comment: @ReynardDroste Are you suggesting that i should get all the characters in one blender file and then rig and animate them ? (that was my initial approach but for some reason when i attached the mesh and the armature for one character, it affected the mesh of other characters as well). Do you have any recommendations for that ?

Comment: @user77239 You said you rigged and animated them separately right? So I assume all 4 characters are in different blend files. If that's the case you can copy paste between open blender windows. Open a new blender window and start to copy them in one by one into the new scene, their rigs should still only affect the mesh that's weighted to them and not other meshes. So no need to rig and animate them all in the same blender file.